Convert Terminals (Robert Chartier) favorites file to mRemoteNG config file
Attempting to convert Terminals (Robert Chartier) favorites file to mRemoteNG config file. Both files are XML. I need to loop through the favorites file that looks like this (C:\Temp\tempTerminals.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<favorites>
 <favorite>
   <protocol>RDP</protocol>
   <port>3389</port>
   <serverName>first.machine.local</serverName>
   <url>rdp://first.machine.local:3389/</url>
   <name>First Machine</name>
   <notes />
   <tags>FM</tags>
   <newWindow>False</newWindow>
   <toolBarIcon />
   <bitmapPeristence>RDP</bitmapPeristence>
   <credential />
   <domainName />
   <desktopSize>AutoScale</desktopSize>
   <desktopSizeHeight>600</desktopSizeHeight>
   <desktopSizeWidth>800</desktopSizeWidth>
   <colors>Bit16</colors>
   <sounds>DontPlay</sounds>
   <redirectClipboard>True</redirectClipboard>
   <enableTLSAuthentication>True</enableTLSAuthentication>
   <enableNLAAuthentication>True</enableNLAAuthentication>
   <idleTimeout>240</idleTimeout>
   <overallTimeout>600</overallTimeout>
   <connectionTimeout>600</connectionTimeout>
   <shutdownTimeout>10</shutdownTimeout>
 </favorite>
</favorites>

And I need to add each of them to an empty mRemoteNG config file that looks like this (C:\Temp\tempRemoteng.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mrng:Connections xmlns:mrng="http://mremoteng.org" Name="Connections" Export="false" 
      EncryptionEngine="AES" BlockCipherMode="GCM" KdfIterations="1000" 
      FullFileEncryption="false" Protected="<A really long value>" ConfVersion="2.6">
    < New nodes are to go here >
</mrng:Connections>

This is what each child node should look like:
<Node Name="<Name from favorite>" Type="Connection" Descr="" Icon="mRemoteNG" 
      Panel="General" Id="<Need new GUID here>" Username="_username_" Domain="_domain_" 
      Password="_password" Hostname="<serverName from favorite>" Protocol="RDP" 
      PuttySession="Default Settings" Port="3389" ConnectToConsole="false"
      UseCredSsp="true" RenderingEngine="IE" ICAEncryptionStrength="EncrBasic" 
      RDPAuthenticationLevel="NoAuth" RDPMinutesToIdleTimeout="0" />

(There's actually a lot more attributes, I just truncated it for example)
I need to modify the Name, Hostname attributes and add a new GUID in the Id attribute.
This code, gives me the error  "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
$terminals = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\tempTerminals.xml"
$terminalsDoc = [xml]$terminals

$remoteNg = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\tempRemoteng.xml"
$remoteNgDoc = [xml]$remoteNg

clear

# Accessing elements
$root = $terminalsDoc.favorites.ChildNodes

$childNode = $remoteNgDoc.ChildNodes[1]

foreach($node in $root) 
{
    $rootValue = $node.name
    $rootURI = $node.serverName

    $newNode = [xml]@"
    <Node Name="$($rootValue)" Type="Connection" Descr="" Icon="mRemoteNG" Panel="General" Id="$(New-Guid)" Username="_username_" Domain="_domain_" Password="_Password_" 
          Hostname="$($rootURI)" Protocol="RDP" PuttySession="Default Settings" Port="3389" ConnectToConsole="false" UseCredSsp="true" RenderingEngine="IE" ICAEncryptionStrength="EncrBasic" RDPAuthenticationLevel="NoAuth" RDPMinutesToIdleTimeout="0" />
"@
 $childNode.AppendChild($newNode)

}

Just having difficulty understanding handling of XML in PowerShell.
BTW, I tried using Import-CliXml on both files and am getting this error:
Import-CliXml : Element 'Objs' with namespace name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04' was not found. Line 1, position 2.


This may be a an error do changes failing a schema check.

To create a new XML element node, call CreateElement on the target document, then set the attribute values programmatically:
foreach($node in $root) 
{
    $rootValue = $node.name
    $rootURI = $node.serverName

    $newNode = $remoteNgDoc.CreateElement('Node') 
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Name', "$rootValue") 
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Type', "Connection") 
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Descr', "")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Icon', "mRemoteNG")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Panel', "General")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Id', "$(New-Guid)")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Username', "_username_")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Domain', "_domain_")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Password', "_Password_")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Hostname', "$rootURI")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Protocol', "RDP")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('PuttySession', "Default Settings")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('Port', "3389")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('ConnectToConsole', "false")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('UseCredSsp', "true")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('RenderingEngine', "IE")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('ICAEncryptionStrength', "EncrBasic")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('RDPAuthenticationLevel', "NoAuth")
    $newNode.SetAttribute('RDPMinutesToIdleTimeout', "0")

    $childNode.AppendChild($newNode) |Out-Null
}


Given you provided XML fragments, consider XSLT which PowerShell can run using .NET's XslCompiledTransform Class with no loops. Specifically, below stylesheet re-styles the element-centric <favorite> nodes to attribute-centric <Node>. You can even pass parameters such as the GUID.
XSLT (save as .xsl, a special .xml file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="guid"/>

    <xsl:template match="/favorites">
      <mrng:Connections xmlns:mrng="http://mremoteng.org" Name="Connections" Export="false" 
            EncryptionEngine="AES" BlockCipherMode="GCM" KdfIterations="1000" 
            FullFileEncryption="false" Protected="&lt;A really long value&gt;" ConfVersion="2.6">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="favorite"/>
      </mrng:Connections>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="favorite">
      <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="server"><xsl:value-of select="serverName"/></xsl:variable>
      
      <Node Name="{$name}" Type="Connection" Descr="" Icon="mRemoteNG" 
            Panel="General" Id="{$guid}" Username="_username_" Domain="_domain_" 
            Password="_password" Hostname="{$server}" Protocol="RDP" 
            PuttySession="Default Settings" Port="3389" ConnectToConsole="false"
            UseCredSsp="true" RenderingEngine="IE" ICAEncryptionStrength="EncrBasic" 
            RDPAuthenticationLevel="NoAuth" RDPMinutesToIdleTimeout="0" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

PowerShell
# Load the style sheet
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\style.xsl")

$argList = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
$argList.AddParam("guid", "", "$(New-Guid)")

# Execute the transform with parameter and output the results to a file
$fs = New-Object IO.FileStream "C:\Path\To\Output.xml", ([System.IO.FileMode]::Create)

try {
    $xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\Input.xml", $argList, $fs)
} catch {
  Write-Host "Error:"
  Write-Host $_
} finally {
    $fs.Dispose()
}

Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<mrng:Connections Name="Connections" Export="false" EncryptionEngine="AES" BlockCipherMode="GCM" KdfIterations="1000" FullFileEncryption="false" Protected="&lt;A really long value&gt;" ConfVersion="2.6" xmlns:mrng="http://mremoteng.org">
  <Node Name="First Machine" Type="Connection" Descr="" Icon="mRemoteNG" Panel="General" Id="299aed4f-bc6a-4bc1-93f2-b6098d867bcb" Username="_username_" Domain="_domain_" Password="_password" Hostname="first.machine.local" Protocol="RDP" PuttySession="Default Settings" Port="3389" ConnectToConsole="false" UseCredSsp="true" RenderingEngine="IE" ICAEncryptionStrength="EncrBasic" RDPAuthenticationLevel="NoAuth" RDPMinutesToIdleTimeout="0" />
</mrng:Connections>

Do note, using .NET's XslCompiledTransform may re-order attributes (though other processors may not) but according to XML standards, XML attribute and namespace declaration order should never matter!

Getting this: Cannot find an overload for "Transform" and the argument count: "3".

Looks like according to the Load signature, there is no (string, arglist, string). But we can stream the resulting file for (string, arglist, stream). See my edit.

BTW - It occurred to me just after answering, PS will pass a single GUID to XSLT document and not for each <Node>. You can use XSLT extensions to generate GUIDs: here and here.
